# How to filter time series if data exists at least data every 6 hours?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, filter, time-series

I'd like to verify if there is data at least once every 6 hours per ID, and filter out the IDs that do not meet this criteria.

essentially a filter: "if ID's data not at least every 6h, drop id from dataframe"

I try to use the same method for filtering one per day, but having trouble adapting the code.

```
# add day column from datetime index
df['1D'] = df.index.day
# reset index
daily = df.reset_index()
# count per ID per day. Result is per ID data of non-zero 
a = daily.groupby(['1D', 'id']).size()
# filter by right join 
filtered = a.merge(df, on = id", how = 'right')
```

I cannot figure out how to adapt this for the following 6hr periods each day: 00:01-06:00, 06:01-12:00, 12:01-18:00, 18:01-24:00.

Comment: can you provide some sample input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby `ID` and then integer divide hour by `6` and get unique counts. In your case it should be greater than or equal to `4` because there are `4` - 6 hour bins in 24 hours and each day has 4 unique bins i.e.

**Bins = 4**

00:01-06:00

06:01-12:00

12:01-18:00

18:01-24:00

**Code**

```
mask = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(lambda x: (x.dt.hour // 6).nunique() >= 4)
df = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use pivot_table with resample which allows to change to arbitrary frequencies. Please see comments for further explanations.

```
# build test data. I need a dummy column to use pivot_table later. Any column with numerical values will suffice
data = [[datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1), 1, 1],
        [datetime(2020, 1, 1, 6), 1, 1],
        [datetime(2020, 1, 1, 12), 1, 1],
        [datetime(2020, 1, 1, 18), 1, 1],
        [datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1), 2, 1],

       ]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=['date', 'id', 'dummy'])
df = df.set_index('date')

# We need a helper dataframe df_tmp.
# Transform id entries to columns. resample with 6h = 360 minutes = 360T. 
# Take mean() because it will produce nan values
# WARNING: It will only work if you have at least one id with observations for every 6h. 
df_tmp = pd.pivot_table(df, columns='id', index=df.index).resample('360T').mean()

# Drop MultiColumnHierarchy and drop all columns with NaN values
df_tmp.columns = df_tmp.columns.get_level_values(1)
df_tmp.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)

# Filter values in original dataframe where 
mask_id = df.id.isin(df_tmp.columns.to_list())
df = df[mask_id]
```

Comment: This is pretty close, however, it removes the 6H of periods of NaNs, which is important to keep.

Comment: Do you mean that in the orignal dataframe are NaN values which you want to keep? In other words: you don't care if an observation has a **meaningful** value; it is enough that it has **a** value, even NaN.

Comment: Sorry for the confustion. I do care if the observation has a meaningful (non NaN) value. As is, the resulting df after df[mask_id] is the same as the input df because there are days with missing data

Comment: Which is beaucse the pivot table excludes the missing data (which is the last ~18 hours)

Comment: There is something about your original dataframe which I do not understand. I assumed with missing days the resulting dataframe would be empty. Can you please post sample data from the last 18 hours?

Answer (score 0):

I kept your requirements on timestamps but I believe you want to use the commented lines in my solution.

```
import pandas as pd

period = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01 00:01:00', '2020-01-01 06:00:00'])
# period = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 06:00:00'])
shift = pd.to_timedelta(['6H', '6H'])

id_with_data = set(df['ID'])
for k in range(4): # for a day (00:01 --> 24:00)
  period_mask = (period[0] <= df.index) & (df.index <= period[1])
  # period_mask = (period[0] <= df.index) & (df.index < period[1]) 
  present_ids = set(df.loc[period_mask, 'ID'])
  id_with_data = id_with_data.intersection(present_ids)
  period += shift

df = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(list(id_with_data))]
```